# Simple middleware pipeline builder (similar to asp.net-core)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, reflection

I created a simple middleware pipeline builder that I want to use for my frameworks. It is similar to how ASP.NET-Core middleware works and uses the same conventions:

> - A public constructor with a parameter of type `RequestDelegate`.
> - A public method named `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync`. This method must:
>
>   - Return a `Task`.
>   - Accept a first parameter of type `HttpContext`.

The only difference is that I use a generic `delegate` for `next` that I renamed:

```
public delegate Task RequestCallback<TContext>(TContext context);
```

#### API

The whole thing is quite simple. It uses a `Stack` to store registered middleware types (currently without constructor parameters) and so that I can process them in the reverse order. I need this to inject the last middleware's `Invoke` as *next* of the one that is going to be created aftewards and so on. The last one, or the first added one, is the starting point.

I use `Autofac` to resolve dependencies.

```
public class PipelineBuilder
{
    private readonly Stack<Type> _middlewareTypes = new Stack<Type>();
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public PipelineBuilder(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public PipelineBuilder Add<T>()
    {
        _middlewareTypes.Push(typeof(T));
        return this;
    }

    public RequestCallback<TContext> Build<TContext>()
    {
        var previous = default(object);
        while (_middlewareTypes.Any())
        {
            var middlewareType = _middlewareTypes.Pop();
            var next = CreateNext<TContext>(previous);
            previous = _lifetimeScope.Resolve(middlewareType, new TypedParameter(typeof(RequestCallback<TContext>), next));
        }

        return CreateNext<TContext>(previous);
    }

    // Using this helper to "catch" the "previous" middleware before it goes out of scope and is overwritten by the loop.
    private RequestCallback<TContext> CreateNext<TContext>(object previous)
    {
        // Doing it here to reflection next time.
        var nextInvoke = previous?.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke") ?? previous?.GetType().GetMethod("InvokeAsync");

        return (RequestCallback<TContext>)(context =>
        {
            if (previous is null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                return (Task)nextInvoke.Invoke(previous, new object[] { context });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Demo

I tested it with four *dummy* middlewares that build a message. Here's the complete code:

```
void Main()
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<M1>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<M2>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<M3>();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<M4>();
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

    var pipelineBuilder = new PipelineBuilder(lifetimeScope);
    pipelineBuilder.Add<M1>();
    pipelineBuilder.Add<M2>();
    pipelineBuilder.Add<M3>();
    pipelineBuilder.Add<M4>();
    var next = pipelineBuilder.Build<TestContext>();
    var context = new TestContext { Message = "" };
    next(context);
    context.Message.Dump(); // --> "Spongebob Squarepants"
}

public class TestContext
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

class M1
{
    private readonly RequestCallback<TestContext> _next;
    public M1(RequestCallback<TestContext> next) => _next = next;
    public Task Invoke(TestContext context)
    {
        context.Message = "Sponge";
        return _next(context);
    }
}

class M2
{
    private readonly RequestCallback<TestContext> _next;
    public M2(RequestCallback<TestContext> next) => _next = next;
    public Task Invoke(TestContext context)
    {
        context.Message += "bob";
        return _next(context);
    }
}

class M3
{
    private readonly RequestCallback<TestContext> _next;
    public M3(RequestCallback<TestContext> next) => _next = next;
    public Task Invoke(TestContext context)
    {
        context.Message += " Square";
        return _next(context);
    }
}

class M4
{
    private readonly RequestCallback<TestContext> _next;
    public M4(RequestCallback<TestContext> next) => _next = next;
    public Task Invoke(TestContext context)
    {
        context.Message += "pants";
        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

#### Questions

What do you think? Can we make it better? Please ignore the missing null-checks... it's an early proof-of-concept.

Comment: I take it that Invoke and InvokeAsync are methods by convention, not by interface?

Comment: @dfhwze exactly. There is no interface.

Comment: And preferring Invoke over InvokeAsync is according to some spec or personal preference?

Comment: @dfhwze haha, just a coincidence. I have no preference towards either of them... although I think `InvokeAsyc` would be more _conventional_ and I didn't cheat by looking at the original source-code :-P so I actually don't know which one of them asp.net-core favors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running through a few ideas in my first pass at the current implementation, I ended up with this refactored approach to simplify your build process

```
public RequestCallback<TContext> Build<TContext>() {
    var next = new RequestCallback<TContext>(context => Task.CompletedTask);
    while (_middlewareTypes.Any()) {
        var middlewareType = _middlewareTypes.Pop();            
        var middlewareInstance = _lifetimeScope.Resolve(middlewareType, new TypedParameter(typeof(RequestCallback<TContext>), next));
        var nextInvoke = getNextInvoke(middlewareType);
        next = (RequestCallback<TContext>)nextInvoke.CreateDelegate(typeof(RequestCallback<TContext>), middlewareInstance);
    }
    return next;
}

MethodInfo getNextInvoke(Type type) {
    return type.GetMethod("Invoke") ?? type.GetMethod("InvokeAsync");
}
```

Since you are already starting at the end of the pipeline, I figured you could have the dummy delegate to begin with

```
var next = new RequestCallback<TContext>(context => Task.CompletedTask);
```

and use that as the next in the pipeline.

From there it was a matter of passing the delegate on to the next in line when resolving the middleware.

Your `CreateNext` seemed a little over complicated at first glance, then I remembered that you can create a delegate directly from a `MethodInfo` using the instance.

```
next = (RequestCallback<TContext>)nextInvoke.CreateDelegate(typeof(RequestCallback<TContext>), middlewareInstance);
```

Using a quick unit test I was able to reproduce your demo to prove my refactor did not break the expected behavior

```
[TestClass]
public class PipelineBuilderTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task PipelineBuilder_Should_Build_Delegate() {
        //Arrange
        var pipelineBuilder = new PipelineBuilder();
        pipelineBuilder.Add<M1>();
        pipelineBuilder.Add<M2>();
        pipelineBuilder.Add<M3>();
        pipelineBuilder.Add<M4>();
        var next = pipelineBuilder.Build<TestContext>();
        var context = new TestContext { Message = "" };
        string expected = "Spongebob Squarepants";

        //Act
        await next(context);

        //Assert (FluentAssertions)
        context.Message.Should().Be(expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, this is a nice _trick_! :-] and with a new generic extension for `CreateDelegate<T>` I can even _suppress_ the repeated types.

Comment: @t3chb0t I had the same thought as  well for it to be more DRY

Comment: I mark your answer because I learned the new `CreateDelegate` method... although after all I wasn't able to use it with the new scenario where the actual `Invoke` has other parameters but the _request_.

Answer (score 2):

#### Conventions

If you want similar behavior as ASP.NET Core, you should check against both methods `Invoke` and `InvokeAsync`. If not, I would prefer to change the order to seek the methods. Postfix `*Async` is a convention to return `Task`.

> View component '...' must have exactly one
>   public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'.

#### Dependencies

You have included a depedency on a third-party library `Autofac`. I would try to prevent this. Specially, since there is an easy way of making this class dependency-free. Use a callback `Func<..>` instead, or an interface `ITypeResolver` if the func is bad for readability.

Comment: I'm kind of _married_ to Autofac lol ;-] it's baked into everthing in my libs :-\

Comment: Does Autofac know you are cheating on her with DynamicException.Create? :p

Comment: haha, she's powerfull, but not almighty so she sometimes needs a little help ;-] I think she even likes having another _compiler_ around.

Comment: I use this builder now to create a new IO-layer pipeline. I had decorators before (ugly) That's so cool now where I can log every file/config/email/http or other resource operation and statistics. Next, I can throw away a lot of logging elsewhere ;-] I turned every resource access into a _REST-controller_. Basiacally it's like asp.net-core for applictaion-io lol

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/he-dev/gunter/blob/dev/Gunter/src/DependencyInjection/Modules/Service.cs#L45)

Answer (score 2):

*(self-answer)*

---

This thing has grown a little bit since I have posted it. I followed most of the suggestions and added some new features: dynamic parameter resolution for middleware constructor and for the `Invoke` methods. I now throw exceptions when *contract* conventions have not been met like invalid middleware constructor, too few or too many invokes or having invalid signatures.

---

Something for my *fans* of the `DynamicException`: it saved me from creating five unnecessary exception classes here.

---

```
public class MiddlewareBuilder
{
    private readonly Stack<(Type MiddlewareType, object[] Parameters)> _middleware = new Stack<(Type MiddlewareType, object[] Parameters)>();

    public Func<Type, object> Resolve { get; set; } = _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("No service for resolving middleware dependencies has been registered.");

    public MiddlewareBuilder Add<T>(params object[] parameters)
    {
        _middleware.Push((typeof(T), parameters));
        return this;
    }

    public RequestCallback<TContext> Build<TContext>()
    {
        var previous = default(object);
        while (_middleware.Any())
        {
            var current = _middleware.Pop();
            var nextCallback = CreateNext<TContext>(previous);
            var parameters = new object[] { nextCallback };
            if (current.Parameters.Any())
            {
                parameters = parameters.Concat(current.Parameters).ToArray();
            }

            var middlewareCtor = current.MiddlewareType.GetConstructor(parameters.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray());
            if (middlewareCtor is null)
            {
                throw DynamicException.Create
                (
                    "ConstructorNotFound",
                    $"Type '{current.MiddlewareType.ToPrettyString()}' does not have a constructor with these parameters: [{parameters.Select(p => p.GetType().ToPrettyString()).Join(", ")}]"
                );
            }

            previous = middlewareCtor.Invoke(parameters);
        }

        return CreateNext<TContext>(previous);
    }


    // Using this helper to "catch" the "previous" middleware before it goes out of scope and is overwritten by the loop.
    private RequestCallback<TContext> CreateNext<TContext>(object middleware)
    {
        // This is the last last middleware and there is nowhere to go from here.
        if (middleware is null)
        {
            return _ => Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var invokeMethods = new[]
        {
            middleware.GetType().GetMethod("InvokeAsync"),
            middleware.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")
        };

        var nextInvokeMethod = invokeMethods.Where(Conditional.IsNotNull).SingleOrThrow
        (
            onEmpty: () => DynamicException.Create("InvokeNotFound", $"{middleware.GetType().ToPrettyString()} must implement either 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'."),
            onMany: () => DynamicException.Create("AmbiguousInvoke", $"{middleware.GetType().ToPrettyString()} must implement either 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke' but not both.")
        );

        var parameters = nextInvokeMethod.GetParameters();

        if (parameters.First().ParameterType != typeof(TContext))
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create
            (
                "InvokeSignature",
                $"{middleware.GetType().ToPrettyString()} Invoke(Async)'s first parameters must be of type '{typeof(RequestCallback<TContext>).ToPrettyString()}'."
            );
        }

        return context =>
        {
            var parameterValues =
                parameters
                    .Skip(1) // TContext is always there.
                    .Select(parameter => Resolve(parameter.ParameterType)) // Resolve other Invoke(Async) parameters.
                    .Prepend(context);

            // Call the actual invoke with its parameters.
            return (Task)nextInvokeMethod.Invoke(middleware, parameterValues.ToArray());
        };

        // I leave this here in case I need it later...
        //return next.CreateDelegate<RequestCallback<TContext>>(middleware);
    }
}
```

I also moved the `Autofac` dependency into a new class. This way I can easily test the main class and use this one with more complex scenarios in production.

```
public class MiddlewareBuilderWithAutofac : MiddlewareBuilder
{
    public MiddlewareBuilderWithAutofac(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        Resolve =
            type =>
                componentContext.IsRegistered(type)
                    ? componentContext.Resolve(type)
                    : throw DynamicException.Create("TypeNotFound", $"Could not resolve '{type.ToPrettyString()}'.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If only one parameter then you can use create delegate else what you have there.

Comment: I am away from my machine at the moment, will review this again later.

Comment: @Nkosi maybe OP should ask follow-up, or we'll get a review of a self-answer, which will get very confusing :p