# Sub-Middleware like options builder for an Asp.Net Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Building upon a recent question I answered here

#### [Simple middleware pipeline builder (similar to asp.net-core)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225978/simple-middleware-pipeline-builder-similar-to-asp-net-core)

I came across a cross site question

#### Stackoverflow: [Adding middleware in Carter framework makes some URL to not trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558181/adding-middleware-in-carter-framework-makes-some-url-to-not-trigger)

which looked like it could benefit from what I had learned from the previous question.

It is related to a GitHub library called [Carter](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter)

> Carter is a library that allows Nancy-esque routing for use with ASP.Net Core.

The OP was hoping to be able to add tasks to the expected delegate for the middleware's [CarterOptions](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter/blob/master/src/CarterOptions.cs) class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes <see cref="CarterOptions"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="before">A global before handler which is invoked before all routes</param>
/// <param name="after">A global after handler which is invoked after all routes</param>
/// <param name="openApiOptions">A <see cref="OpenApiOptions"/> instance to configure OpenApi</param>
public CarterOptions(Func<HttpContext, Task<bool>> before = null, Func<HttpContext, Task> after = null, OpenApiOptions openApiOptions = null) {
    //...
}
```

This is the before code where the options is created directly.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    var options = new CarterOptions(
        before: ctx => {
            ctx.Request.Header["x-request-id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            return this.BeforeLog(ctx);
        },
        after: ctx => AfterLog(ctx)
    );

    app.UseCarter(options);

    //...
}
```

I came up with the following builder for the middleware's options class

```
sealed class CarterOptionsBuilder {
    delegate Task<bool> BeforeDelegate(HttpContext context);
    delegate Task AfterDelegate(HttpContext context);

    private readonly Stack<Func<BeforeDelegate, BeforeDelegate>> befores = new Stack<Func<BeforeDelegate, BeforeDelegate>>();
    private readonly Stack<Func<AfterDelegate, AfterDelegate>> afters = new Stack<Func<AfterDelegate, AfterDelegate>>();

    public CarterOptionsBuilder AddBeforeHook(Func<HttpContext, Task<bool>> handler) {
        befores.Push(next => async context => {
            return await handler(context) && await next(context);
        });
        return this;
    }

    public CarterOptionsBuilder AddAfterHook(Func<HttpContext, Task> handler) {
        afters.Push(next => context => {
            handler(context);
            return next(context);
        });
        return this;
    }

    public CarterOptions Build(OpenApiOptions openApiOptions = null) {
        var before = new BeforeDelegate(c => Task.FromResult(true));
        while (befores.Any()) {
            var current = befores.Pop();
            before = current(before);
        }
        var after = new AfterDelegate(c => Task.CompletedTask);
        while (afters.Any()) {
            var current = afters.Pop();
            after = current(after);
        }
        return new CarterOptions(before.Invoke, after.Invoke, openApiOptions);
    }
}
```

Which allowed for functionality like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
     CarterOptions options = new CarterOptionsBuilder()
        .AddBeforeHook(this.AddRequestId)
        .AddBeforeHook(this.BeforeLog)
        .AddAfterHook(this.AfterLog)
        .Build();

    app.UseCarter(options);
}

private Task AfterLog(HttpContext arg) {
    //...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private Task<bool> BeforeLog(HttpContext arg) {
    //...
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}

private Task<bool> AddRequestId(HttpContext ctx) {
    ctx.Request.Header["x-request-id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

This does open extensibility for more customization like

```
public static CarterOptionsBuilder AddLog(this CarterOptionsBuilder builder) {
    return builder
        .AddBeforeHook(this.BeforeLog)
        .AddAfterHook(this.AfterLog);        
}
private static Task AfterLog(HttpContext arg) {
    //...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static Task<bool> BeforeLog(HttpContext arg) {
    //...
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Might consider contributing it as a pull-request to the repository.

Is it even worth the trouble?

Thoughts and opinions on the design, given the original feature request.

Comment: Cool, inspired by my question ;-) I think `HandleAfter` is incorrect. `after(context);` should be placed below `return next(context);`... if this means _after-a-request_.

Comment: @t3chb0t in this case the delegate(s) is not after a request per say, but a desired action/task that is to be perform after a request.

Comment: ok, I guess then I need to take a look at that framework first as these concepts are new to me.

Comment: @t3chb0t it is technically two pipelines. one is invoked before request, the other after. But each pipeline acts like a normal pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't undestand that framework but there are few minor things that I think could be improved anyway:

- `AddBeforeHook` & `AddAfterHook` could actually use the `BeforeDelegate` & `AfterDelegate` respectively instead of `Func`s.
- I would rename `handler` to `before` & `after` since the third one is already called `next`. I find this way it would be clearer what they handle.
- I think you should be able to rewrite the `while`s in the `Build` method with an `Aggregate` like:

  ```
  before = befores.Aggregate(before, (current, next) => next(current));
  ```

  or even

  ```
  var before = befores.Aggregate(new BeforeDelegate(c => Task.FromResult(true)), (current, next) => next(current));
  ```

  Elements are enumerated in the `Pop` order.

Comment: Like the aggregates idea.

Comment: Had them named previously before and after, but thought they caused confusion which to me was evident in your comment.

Comment: @Nkosi my comment was a sign of a lack of knowledge about how this framework works. I think to someone who knows the ins and outs of it, make `before` and `after` probably more sense than just `handler`.